# AJAX JQUERY variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to send data with ajax in php, but I use an on jQuery click ( on a button which send data while `quantity > 1`), but I have an error, php does not recognize my two variables : `name` and `nb`.

This is my JQUERY/AJAX :

```
$('.btn-circle').on('click', function(){
    var name = $('.quantite').attr('name');
    var nb = $('.quantite').text();
});

$('#form_top_ten').submit(function() {
    if(nb>=1){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "handle_form/commande.php",
            data: {nb:nb,name:name}
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

and this my php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once '../includes/config.inc.php';

    $id_user = $_SESSION['id_user'];
    $quantite = $_POST['nb'];
    $article = $_POST['name'];

    if(isset($quantite)){
        $req = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO commande_articles(id_user,quantite,article) VALUES(:id_user,:quantite,:article)');
        $req->execute(array(
            'quantite' => $quantite,
            'article' => $article,
            'id_user' => $id_user
            ));
    }   
    else {
        echo('erreur');
    }
?>
```

Comment: You are creating variables in one function and then you are trying to access them in another function. It is different scope.

Comment: yes thanks i know that but i don't know how i must do for re-use this variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the variables on a higher scope. Try this:

```
var name,nb;
$('.btn-circle').on('click', function()
{
     name = $('.quantite').attr('name');
     nb = $('.quantite').text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, variables have function scope. What this means is, your variables name and nb are within an anonymous function, and hence they are unavailable outside. The quickest fix is to just remove the "var" keyword from your variable declarations. This will make the scope of these variables global instantly, and your code should work.

A neater solution, however, would be to declare them outside the anonymous function, and then refer them within the function - this way, you have more control over the scope of these variables (Refer Siamak's answer above)